# openssl api verify the public key matches private key

Tags: c, openssl

How do I write an openssl server that on a single port has two different active RSA private keys? The openssl documentation seems to implies there can only be one rsa private key active at time with in a context. So I was thinking I have two active context, but what is the code to handle figuring out which connection matches which context. Or am I going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of an odd thing to want, but it's doable.  You can maintain two active `SSL_CTX` handles, each of which has a different certificate/private key pair loaded.

When you accept a new connection, just pick the right `SSL_CTX` to generate the new `SSL` handle from (using `SSL_new()`).  As for "which connection matches which certificate" - that's up to you to determine.  You could decide based on the peer address of the connection, or you might have a plain text protocol prior to starting SSL where the peer identifies the certificate it is expecting.